# Fullscreen Photo/Video Slideshow App?

Tags: windows, slideshow

I have a folder that contains a lot of subfolders which include photos and/or videos. Is there any free application that would display them in a random slideshow? It's something I want to run on a PC mounted on a wall. I point it to that folder and it starts displaying it, with some random/nice transitions. No need for anything more fancy, except maybe Previous/Next controls.

**Edit:** Just a quick clarification. Those pictures change all the time, and there are many of them. It's supposed to be in a store to display product pictures, so it's not like someone is actively watching the whole show. Currently, there are around 150,000 pictures or videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went with Windows Photo Gallery in the end. Needs some manual updating, but works otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Media Player, besides playing videos and music, also play pictures. Simply drag the folder to WMP to make a Now Playing list then press Play and set it to Full Screen. You can also enable Shuffle. Transitions wise there is only a fade effect. *(I don't think I'm alone in saying I've always found any motion or random disintegration effects etc highly irritating)*

Comment: Does indeed handle subfolders. Nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PPT?it can display the picture and videos as a slide.

Answer (score 0):

I found ScreenPaver. I decided to use BitTorrent Synch on my NAS where I drop in new images and it Synchs up with my new Photo Frame PC.

Pretty awesome software and quiet surprised there are not more available. I posted this here because I found this question before finding the the software. I hope it can help somebody.

http://www.screenpaver.com/index.html